# WebDriver - wait for element using Java

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking for something similar to `waitForElementPresent` to check whether element is displayed before I click it. I thought this can be done by `implicitWait`, so I used the following:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and then click by

```
driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty(vName))).click();
```

Unfortunately, sometimes it waits for the element and sometimes not. I looked for a while and found this solution :

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    if (second >= 10)
        fail("timeout : " + vName);
    try {
        if (driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty(vName))).isDisplayed())
            break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        writeToExcel("data.xls", e.toString(), parameters.currentTestRow, 46);
    }
}
driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty(vName))).click();
```

And it waited all right, but before timing out it had to wait 10 times 5, 50 seconds. A bit much. So I set the implicitly wait to 1sec and all seemed fine until now. Because now some things wait 10s before timeout but some other things time out after 1s.

How do you cover the waiting for element present/visible in your code? Any hint is appreciable.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

This is how I do it in my code.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>));
```

to be precise.

See also:

- [org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) for similar shortcuts for various wait scenarios.
- [org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) for its various constructors.

Comment: Thanks! If I only knew sooner about this class my life would be easier :)

Comment: How do I incorporate your code into this format ?  `@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "signup-button")
 WebElement signUpButton;` Moreover,  I still get a NPE with your code. Looks like it is trying to get elementToBeClickable. How can we use this method when the element is not loaded ?

Answer (score 16):

You can use Explicit wait or Fluent Wait

Example of Explicit Wait -

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverRefrence,20);
WebElement aboutMe;
aboutMe= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("about_me")));
```

Example of Fluent Wait -

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)                            
.withTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)          
.pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)          
.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);    

  WebElement aboutMe= wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {       
public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) { 
return driver.findElement(By.id("about_me"));     
 }  
});
```

Check this [TUTORIAL](http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/10/implicit-wait-explicit-wait-and-fluent.html) for more details.

Comment: This method is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

We're having a lot of race conditions with `elementToBeClickable`. See https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2313. Something along these lines worked reasonably well even if a little brute force

```
Awaitility.await()
        .atMost(timeout)
        .ignoreException(NoSuchElementException.class)
        .ignoreExceptionsMatching(
            Matchers.allOf(
                Matchers.instanceOf(WebDriverException.class),
                Matchers.hasProperty(
                    "message",
                    Matchers.containsString("is not clickable at point")
                )
            )
        ).until(
            () -> {
                this.driver.findElement(locator).click();
                return true;
            },
            Matchers.is(true)
        );
```

Answer (score -5):

Above wait statement is a nice example of Explicit wait.

As Explicit waits are intelligent waits that are confined to a particular web element(as mentioned in above x-path).

By Using explicit waits you are basically telling WebDriver at the max it is to wait for X units(whatever you have given as timeoutInSeconds) of time before it gives up.

Comment: Add some code snippet to your answer, as other users might sort the answers differently and the context for "Above" might change for them.

Comment: it's been 5 years, and still waiting on code snippet so this can make sense for others who are in search of information on the topic.

Comment: If anyone would like to learn more about this answer. 
https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html