# Webdriver : Waiting for JavaScript automation to complete (Java)

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium

Im trying to write an automated test for a dynamic web application. When the page loads, all the elements are "visible" and "enabled" but my test keeps failing due to "element not clickable".

This is because the page starts uses JavaScript automation where all the elements are present but hidden by another div that slow expands and reveals the elements behind it. So, using an explicit wait of visibilityof or elementtobeclickable doesn't work. They still fail as it says the div gets the click instead of the element I want to click.

Any suggestions on how to wait for the JavaScript automation to complete?

Comment: You could wait for an element to become visible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736027/webdriver-wait-for-element.

Comment: You could get the "element" by its' "id".

Comment: u can add the wait method to that element until it loads....