# Can't read an xpath element with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

for some reason when I try to read the xpath while web scraping it returns []. See the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

PATH = 'D:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

url2 = 'https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?NumeroSequencialDocumento={}&CodigoTipoInstituicao=1'.format('91514')

driver.get(url2)

time.sleep(2)

variavel2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_cphPopUp_tbDados"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]')

print(variavel2)
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps [selenium waits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27603477/11746212) might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600906/python-selenium-how-to-wait-before-clicking-on-link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251939/wait-until-button-is-clicked-in-selenium-webdriver-to-click-on-next-button

Comment: @IronMan Hi I tried to use the WebDriverWait but it raises TimeoutException error

Comment: @Rapha Your element target inside a frame.

Comment: it's an iframe. See: https://www.techbeamers.com/switch-between-iframes-selenium-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page uses an iframe so you need to switch to the iframe.

Try this:

```
url2 = 'https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?NumeroSequencialDocumento={}&CodigoTipoInstituicao=1'.format('91514')

driver.get(url2)

time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.frame("iFrameFormulariosFilho")
variavel2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_cphPopUp_tbDados"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]')

print(variavel2)
```

Comment: Hi! Worked with: 

`driver.switch_to.frame("iFrameFormulariosFilho")`

Answer (score 1):

The table seems to load a little bit later, so you will need waits:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ctl00_cphPopUp_tbDados"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]')))
```

Comment: Hi I tried to use the WebDriverWait but it raises TimeoutException error