# in selemium webdriver not able to switch over window (i am using java)

Tags: java, selenium

this is my code 
wait method is not working
switching over windows is not working 
please help me to get over this issue

### i am using selenium 3.01 jars

```
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WindowHandling extends BaseClass
{
public static void main(String args[])
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\driver\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("file://D:/8850OS_Code/Chapter 3/HTML/Window.html");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String window1 = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("First Window Handle is: " + window1);
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Google Search"));
    link.click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String window2 = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("Second Window Handle is: " + window2);
    System.out.println("Number of Window Handles so for: "+           driver.getWindowHandles().size());
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.switchTo().window(window1);
    System.out.println("task done ");
}

}
```

---

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422661/selenium-implicitlywait-not-working) SO question.

Comment: First: And what is problem? Second: Do you know that Selenium wait is something different then sleep actual thread?

Answer (score 0):

Switching windows doesn't work for you because you are switching to the currently focused (first) window. If you check `window1` and `window2` values you will see they are the same: the window handle of the first window. To switch to the new window you need to switch to the handle that is **different** from the current window handle

```
String window1 = driver.getWindowHandle();
for (String windowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (!windowHandle.equals(window1)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
    }
}

String window2 = driver.getWindowHandle(); // now it will be the window handle of the second window
```

And to close the new window and switch back

```
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(window1);
```

As for the wait, `implicitlyWait` is defined one time after creating the `WebDriver`, it will be valid for the entire life span of th driver and it means the driver will wait **up** to the specified amount of time until the elements are found when using `driver.findElement()`. You can see more about waits [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

Comment: code above  is showing error
i am new to  cam you suggest easy way to learn selenium 
or if you can teach me
any suggestion is most welocme

Comment: @MasterTester You have to be more specific about what the error is. And the best way to learn is to try.

Comment: if you don't mind , is there way apart from this where  i can contact you so that i can share my code with you , i can learn something . if you don't want then sorry in advance