# Synchronization with implicitwait() do not work, why?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying synchronization with selenium webdriver and something is not working with implicitlyWait().

The way I understand implicitlyWait(..) is that the code is **waiting** until the element is available for a **max of time**.

The code below crash with the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

The System.out ist printing: -->> false true false (isDiplayed(), isEnabled(), is Selected())

```
private static WebDriver driver;    
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
         setupWebDriverChrome();
        //Thread.sleep(1000);
        final String cssSelectorFromAirport = "div.od-airportselector.airportselector_root input[tabindex='11']";
        final By cssSelector = By.cssSelector(cssSelectorFromAirport);
        WebElement fromAirportElement = driver.findElement(cssSelector);
        System.out.println("-->> " + fromAirportElement.isDisplayed() + " " + fromAirportElement.isEnabled() + " " + fromAirportElement.isSelected());       
        fromAirportElement.clear();
        fromAirportElement.sendKeys("MUC");
    }

    private static void setupWebDriverChrome() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\...\\chromedriver.exe");
        setupLocation();
    }
    private static void setupLocation() {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);     
        driver.get("https://www.opodo.de/");
    }
```

I tried that also with the Geckodriver with the same result.

I have also increased the wait time but same result.

The only way to make it works, is to use Thread.sleep() (Commented above)

**EDIT**
Pls. note that I do not see any duplication with [Selenium implicitwait not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422661/selenium-implicitlywait-not-working).

Comment: @Janith1024 I have seen the thread yor mean but I do not see any duplication. If you mean there is a duplication pls. explain why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait that your element is clickable. Try adding this:

```
 WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorFromAirport)));
```

So:

```
    setupWebDriverChrome();
    //Thread.sleep(1000);
    final String cssSelectorFromAirport = "div.od-airportselector.airportselector_root input[tabindex='11']";
    WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorFromAirport)));
    /*final By cssSelector = By.cssSelector(cssSelectorFromAirport);
    WebElement fromAirportElement = driver.findElement(cssSelector);
    System.out.println("-->> " + fromAirportElement.isDisplayed() + " " + fromAirportElement.isEnabled() + " " + fromAirportElement.isSelected());*/
    element.clear();
    element.sendKeys("MUC");
```

**EDIT**

From the [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) :

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain
>   amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are
>   not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the
>   implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

This means, in your example, that selenium found the element but it isn't yet "clickable".

You can see this also in your test. If you take a look to:

```
System.out.println("-->> " + fromAirportElement.isDisplayed() + " " + fromAirportElement.isEnabled() + " " + fromAirportElement.isSelected() );
```

When it fails, the output is:

```
-->> false true false
```

While when it works:

```
-->> true true false
```

Comment: Thanks, but why is the implicitlyWait() not waiting untill the element is clickable?

Comment: If you are going to use `WebDriverWait`, which is a best practice, just make sure that you aren't also using implicit wait. This is warned against in the [official docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits). `WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.`