# What is the internal working difference between Implicit Wait and Explicit Wait

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait, implicitwait

**Explicit wait example**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement myDynamicElement= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

**Implicit wait example**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = driver.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
```

Let say myDynamicElement is visible at 6th second,
So in both the cases driver will wait till 6th seconds and control will move to the consecutive written statement, I want to understand that how implicit and explicit wait are different from each other in this case? how do they work internally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between Implicit wait Vs. Explicit wait in selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656615/what-is-difference-between-implicit-wait-vs-explicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: There is a lot of information out on the web and SO already. What have you read? What specifically don't you understand. It doesn't seem like you've done any research which is a requirement for a question on SO.

Answer (score 3):

### Implicit Wait :

[Implicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium/45674706#45674706) is the way to configure the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance to poll the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) for a configured amount of time when it tries to find an element or find a group/collection of elements if they are not immediately available. As per the current *W3C specification* the default time is configured to **`0`**. We can configure the time for the [Implicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989984/selenium-implicitly-wait-doesnt-work/48991017#48991017) any where within our script/program and can reconfigure it as per our necessity. Once we set [Implicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767355/implicit-wait-command-not-working-selenium-webdriver-c-sharp/46769081#46769081) it will be valid for the lifetime of the *WebDriver* instance.

### References

A couple of references:

- [Detailed discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium/45674706#45674706)
- [Detailed documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits).

---

### Explicit Wait :

[Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706693/how-to-combine-implicit-and-explicit-timeouts-in-selenium/52707885#52707885) is a code block you define, configure and implement for the *WebDriver* instance to wait for a certain condition to be met before proceeding for the next line of code. WebDriverWait along with certain methods/clauses of [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) is one way to implement [Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759).

### References

A couple of references:

- [Detailed discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759)
- [Detailed documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits).

---

### Getting Granular :

As per your query *...Let say myDynamicElement is visible at 6th second, So in both the cases driver will wait till 6th seconds and control will move to the consecutive written statement...*

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

*Implicit Wait* would poll the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) for the entire **10 secs** irrespective of whether *myDynamicElement* (or multiple elements matching your locator) is visible at 4th / 6th / 8th second. So, in this case, your script gets *delayed by **4** secs*.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement myDynamicElement= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

*Explicit Wait* would wait for **maximum of 10 secs** for the element `someid` to turn clickable (Displayed and Enabled). The *WebElement* is returned back as soon as the *ExpectedConditions* is met. If the *ExpectedConditions* is not met for the entire duration of the configured timeline, you see the proper *Exception*.

Comment: HI, you have to directed me few days back to refer to know what's the advantage of explicit over implicit. I think the first two paragraph is not pointing the important difference and the getting granular answer is completely wrong. Let me explain you ... (continued in next comment)

Comment: First of all, the difference between implicit wait and explicit wait is, Implicit wait is set within the driver, but explicit wait it not set within the driver, it's set in the local language binding. Second mistake is, neither of the waitings are static waiting, If timings are set for 10 seconds, if element is available in 5 seconds, both would immediately allow the further action to take place.

Answer (score 0):

**Implicit waits** are used to provide a waiting time (say 30 seconds) between each consecutive test steps across the entire test script or program. Next step only executed when the 30 Seconds (or whatever time is given is elapsed) after execution of previous step

Syntax:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Explicit waits** are used to halt the execution till the time a particular condition is met or the maximum time which is defined , has elapsed. Implicit wait has applied  between each consecutive test steps across the entire test script or programs while Explicit waits are applied for a particular instance only.

Syntax:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable("Locator"));
```