# Implicit vs Explicit vs Fluent Wait

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, implicitwait, fluentwait

What is difference in between Implicit, Explicit, Fluent Wait ?

If we set 10 seconds in Implicit wait and before 10 seconds, within 3 seconds only element get located.

That time what will happen ? It will wait for 10 seconds or proceed further.

Comment: Same Question for Explicit Wait, If I get full filled the expected condition before time. At that time it will proceed or Wait for mention time ?

Comment: Please google the answer before posting question here, if you have specific doubt please update the question.

Answer (score 7):

### ImplicitWait

[ImplicitWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) is an implementation to configure the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance i.e. the *driver* to poll the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) for a certain amount of time (interms of `NANOSECONDS`, `MICROSECONDS`, `MILLISECONDS`, `SECONDS`, `MINUTES`, `HOURS` or `DAYS`) when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is **0** which means the *driver* when finds an instruction to find an element or elements, the search starts and results are available on immediate basis.

In this case, after a fresh loading of a Webpage an element or elements may be / may not be found on an immediate search. So your [Automation Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013692/what-is-test-automation-framework-in-selenium/52705196#52705196) may be facing any of these exceptions:

- `NoSuchElementException`
- `TimeoutException`
- `ElementNotVisibleException`
- `ElementNotSelectableException`

Hence you need to induce [ImplicitWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium/45674706#45674706). By introducing [ImplicitWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989984/selenium-implicitly-wait-doesnt-work/48991017#48991017) the *driver* will poll the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) for the configured amount of time looking out for the element or elements. By that time the element or elements for which you had been looking for may be available in the DOM. As in your code you have already set [ImplicitWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767355/implicit-wait-command-not-working-selenium-webdriver-c-sharp/46769081#46769081) to a value of **10** seconds, the *driver* will poll the DOM for **10** seconds.

- Python:

  ```
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
  ```
- Java:

  ```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```

Finally, once you set the *ImplicitWait*, the *WebDriver* instance i.e. the *driver* is able to carry this configuration  till its lifetime. But if you need to change the coarse of time for the *WebDriver* instance i.e. the *driver* to **wait** then you can reconfigure it as follows:

- Python:

  ```
  driver.implicitly_wait(5)
  ```
- Java:

  ```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```

If at any point of time you want to nullify the *ImplicitWait* you can reconfigure it as follows:

- Python:

  ```
  driver.implicitly_wait(0)
  ```
- Java:

  ```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```

---

### Fluent Wait

[Fluent Wait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) is the implementation of the [Wait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Wait.html) interface through which we can configure the **timeout** and *polling interval* on the fly. An instance of *FluentWait* can be defined to configure the maximum amount of time to wait for a condition as well as the frequency at which the condition must be checked. User can also configure the wait to ignore specific types of *exceptions* while waiting for an element, such as *NoSuchElementException* on the page.

- Usage:

  ```
     // Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
     // for its presence once every 5 seconds.
     Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
         .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
         .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
         .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

     WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
       public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
         return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
       }
     });
  ```

---

### ExplicitWait

[ExplicitWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518467/how-to-properly-configure-implicit-explicit-waits-and-pageloadtimeout-through/50524225#50524225) commonly known as [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) is a specialized implementation of [FluentWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) through which user can define, configure and implement for the *WebDriver* instance to wait for a certain condition to be met before proceeding for the next line of code.  There are some methods that helps us to implement [ExplicitWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168663/skip-waiting-for-a-website-timer-selenium-python/50168869#50168869) that will wait only as long as required. [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) is one of the way [ExplicitWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759) can be achieved.

### An Example:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
.
.
.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("element_xpath")));
element.click();
```

### Explanation:

This implementation of *ExplicitWait* waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a `TimeoutException` or if it finds the element then it will return within 0 to 10 seconds. *WebDriverWait* by default calls the *ExpectedCondition* every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully. A successful return value for the *ExpectedCondition* function type is a `Boolean` value of true or a not-null object.

---

### Expected Conditions:

There are some frequently encountered conditions when automating Web Browsers for *Testing Web/Mobile Applications*. The Java, C# and Python bindings include those convenient methods so we don’t have to write-up an *ExpectedCondition* class ourselves or create our own utility package for them. Some of the *Expected Conditions* are:

- `alertIsPresent()`
- `elementToBeClickable(locator)`
- `elementToBeSelected(WebElement)`
- `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(locator)`
- `invisibilityOf(element)`

You can find about the all the methods supported by [Expected Conditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) here.

---

### This particular query :

- When searching for a single element, the driver will poll the OM until the element has been found or the configured timeout expires before throwing a `NoSuchElementException`.
- When searching for multiple elements, the driver will poll the DOM until at least one element has been found or the configured timeout has expired.

So as per the first case, driver will wait for **3 seconds only**.

Answer (score 1):

If we set 10 seconds in Implicit wait and before 10 seconds, within 3 seconds only element get located.

That time it will proceed further and not wait for set time..

Answer (score 0):

The implicit wait will tell to the web driver to wait for certain amount of time before it throws a "NoSuchElementException". The default setting is 0. Once we set the time, web driver will wait for that time before throwing an exception. If you have given 10 sec as wait time, but element is identified at 3 sec, then it will go to next step after 3 secs.

An explicit wait is code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code. The explicit wait will tell the web driver to wait for certain conditions like visibilityOfElementLocated and maximum amount of time before throwing NoSuchElementException exception. You can refer this - https://qaautomation.expert/2019/07/18/implicit-explicit-fluent-wait-in-selenium-webdriver/