# Selenium IDE step passes but does not enter text into text box

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to get the IDE to run a test that fills out Username and Password fields. This test used to work until we implented SSO recently.  Now the first password box does not fill in even though the step passes.

The element id="password"

Screenshots

[Password field is skipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eYWg.jpg)

[All the steps say they were successfully run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLBdm.jpg)

I have tried changing the Command to Focus, ClickAt, SendKeys, Type and FireEvent but nothing I try works. I have looked around and did not see anything similar to this asked.  Anyone come across an issue like this?  I am stumped.

[Gif of password field behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SolX.gif)

Comment: Can you try to make a halt after filling up `id="email"` and `element id="password"`. IMO, either the `email` or the `password` gets rendered within the DOM through a JS and you have to wait for completion.

Comment: More info - The password box is shaded until I click inside it and then it turns white and shows the cursor.  I'm guessing that the test is not seeing this field active until it is clicked into?  The 2nd password box does not do this. 
Added a gif to show this.  "Gif of password field behavior"

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons why the `Password` field doesn't gets populated as follows :

- As you provide **Email Address** just before **Password**, there is a possibility that a **`JavaScript`** validates the `Email Address` (once filled up / [**`onfocusout`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/onfocusout/info) event) if the same `Email Address` already exists in the `Database`. In that case the `Password` field won't be **interactable** untill the `JavaScript`/`AJAX Call` is completed.
- The `Password` field seems to have some criteria as to include some `Uppercase Letter`/`Number` etc. So, if you invoke **`sendkeys()`** with a **Character Sequence** which doesn't matches the mentioned criteria the **`JavaScript`** validating the **Character Sequence** erases/removes the **Character Sequence** completely.

### Solution :

You need to induce [**`Explicit Wait`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) i.e. [**`WebDriverWait`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145111/implicit-vs-explicit-vs-fluent-wait/48162909#48162909) for the **`Password`** field to be `clickable` through [**`ExpectedConditions`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) clase as [**elementToBeClickable**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) and then invoke **`sendkeys()`** with a **`Character Sequence`** fulfilling the mentioned criteria mentioned beside the `Password` field.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that there is some event attached to the password field. It could also be the browser. From my experience, Firefox works better with Selenium.

I would inspect the input field to see if there are any events or functions that block you from entering text. If there are, use the execute script Selenium IDE command to run a JS script that can remove it.