# Difference between explicit wait and Fluent wait with respect to current selenium 3.14 version

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I understand that this question has all possible duplicates. But the thing is, i wanted to know the difference with respect to current version of selenium.

My point of view is, both the wait has options to Poll the time and ignore the exceptions, then whats the advantage of using this fluent wait

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implicit vs Explicit vs Fluent Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145111/implicit-vs-explicit-vs-fluent-wait)

Comment: Nope it does not because both explicit and fluent has polling timeouts and ignore methods available. Apart from customized conditions what's the exact difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't different types of waiting, `WebDriverWait` is a specialized version of `FluentWait` with some different constructor options.

In the WebDriver java library, there are 3 types in the inheritance tree of WebDriverWait:

`Wait` is a generic interface for waiting until a condition is true or not null.  Very basic and doesn't define how any of this is done.

`FluentWait` is an implementation of the `Wait` interface that may have its timeout and polling interval configured on the fly.  This class is generic and requires a type `<T>`

`WebDriverWait` extends `FluentWait` and is a specialization that uses `WebDriver` instances.

Prefer WebDriverWait over FluentWait when your generic type `<T>` would be `<WebDriver>`.  It aims to ease construction.

Given this instance of WebDriverWait

```java
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
```

This is what an equivalent FluentWait looks like to create

```java
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver, new SystemClock(), Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER);
    wait.withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    wait.pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500));
    wait.ignoring(NotFoundException.class);
```

This is as far as the difference goes.  The resulting object will behave the same.  WebDriverWait just gives you those defaults for free.

Comment: I agree to your point, after looking into the documentation i could see more or less both has the same mechanism and share same methods. But i am still ore curious on whats the exact difference between the waits. If both does the same then why fluent wait has a subclass webdriverwait. Any practical difference would be appreciate