# How to click on this specific element using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriverwait

I've tried lots of ways but none seem to work its not a clear `id="ezidgrab"` the element can be found on this url: https://www.ahem.email/mailbox/QI2R89LNDT but how do I click the email there with selenium?

What I have tried:

1.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[contains(text(), 'Thank you for registering your email')]")).Click();
```

2.

```
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("mat-list-item")).Click();
```

3.

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("mat-list-item-content")).Click();
```

and the html of the link:

```
<app-email-info _ngcontent-ahem-c5="" _nghost-ahem-c9="">
   <mat-list-item _ngcontent-ahem-c9="" 
                  class="ahem-hand-pointer mat-list-item ahem-email-unread mat-3-line">
      <div class="mat-list-item-content">
         <div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
         <div class="mat-list-text">
            <h2 _ngcontent-ahem-c9="" class="mat-line" mat-line="">Jagex</h2>
            <p _ngcontent-ahem-c9="" 
               class="mat-line" 
               mat-line="">Thank you for registering your email</p>
            <p _ngcontent-ahem-c9="" class="mat-line" mat-line="">9 minutes ago</p>
         </div>
         <fa-icon _ngcontent-ahem-c9="" class="ng-fa-icon">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="envelope" class="svg-inline--fa fa-envelope fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
               <path fill="currentColor" d="M464 64H48C21.49 64 0 85.49 0 112v288c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h416c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48V112c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48zm0 48v40.805c-22.422 18.259-58.168 46.651-134.587 106.49-16.841 13.247-50.201 45.072-73.413 44.701-23.208.375-56.579-31.459-73.413-44.701C106.18 199.465 70.425 171.067 48 152.805V112h416zM48 400V214.398c22.914 18.251 55.409 43.862 104.938 82.646 21.857 17.205 60.134 55.186 103.062 54.955 42.717.231 80.509-37.199 103.053-54.947 49.528-38.783 82.032-64.401 104.947-82.653V400H48z"></path>
            </svg>
         </fa-icon>
      </div>
   </mat-list-item>
</app-email-info>
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//p[contains(text(), 'Thank you for registering your email')]"}

Comment: Also please post what error you are getting.

Comment: Is that the *rendered* HTML as it appears in the browser document object model? We need to see that.

Comment: its the html from inspect element. Do you need to see the html from view source?

Comment: Inspect element should be fine. Thanks!

Comment: The HTML you posted does not include an e-mail link. You are just clicking on a paragraph tag. Is that text actually clickable due to JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to `Click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div.mat-list-text>h2"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='mat-list-text']/h2"))).Click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to click on the item?

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ahem-email-list-item")).Click();
```

Comment: Yeah just tried it again: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ahem\-email\-list\-item"}

Comment: I don't see that in the HTML posted in the question. Is that element elsewhere on the page?

Comment: The item that you have to click is one level above of the app-email-info tag. Are you on the app-email-info scope?