# selenium implicitly wait doesn't work

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, web-crawler, implicitwait

This is the first time I use selenium and headless browser as I want to crawl some web page using ajax tech.

The effect is great, but for some case it takes too much time to load the whole page(especially when some resource is unavailable),so I have to set a time out for the selenium.

First of all I tried `set_page_load_timeout()` and `set_script_timeout()`,but when I set these timeouts, I won't get any page source if the page doesn't load completely, as the codes below:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
driver.set_script_timeout(5)
try:
    driver.get(url)
except Exception:
    driver.execute_script('window.stop()')

print driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')  # raise TimeoutException this line.
```

so I try to using Implicitly Wait and Conditional Wait, like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=path)
print("Firefox Headless Browser Invoked")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
start = time.time()
driver.get(url)
end = time.time()
print 'time used: %s s' % str(end - start)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 2, 0.5).until(expected.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))
    print driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text
except Exception:
    driver.execute_script('window.stop()')
```

This time I got the content that I want.However,it takes a very long time(40+ seconds),that means the timeout I set for 2 seconds doesn't work at all.

In my view, it seems like the `driver.get()` call ends until the browser stop loading the page, only after that the codes below can work, and you can not kill the `get()` call or you'll get nothing.
But this is very different from the selenium docs, I REALLY wonder where is the mistake.

environment: OSX 10.12, selenium 3.0.9 with FireFox & GoogleChrome Headless(both latest version.)

--- update ----

Thanks for help.I change the code as below, using `WebDriverWait()` alone, but there still exist cases that the call last for a very long time, far more than the timeout that I set.
Wonder if I can stop the page load immediately as the time is out?

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=path)
print("Firefox Headless Browser Invoked")
start = time.time()
driver.get('url')
end = time.time()
print 'time used: %s s' % str(end - start)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 2, 0.5).until(expected.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))
    print driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text
except Exception:
    driver.execute_script('window.stop()')
driver.quit()
```

Here is a terminal output in test:

```
Firefox Headless Browser Invoked
time used: 44.6049938202 s
```

according to the code this means the `driver.get()` call takes 44 seconds to finish call, which is unexpected,I wonder if I misunderstood the behavior of the headless browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question *it takes too much time to load the whole page(especially when some resource is unavailable)* is pretty much possible if the *Application Under Test* (**AUT**) uses *JavaScript* or *AJAX Calls*.

- In your first scenario you have induced both `set_page_load_timeout(5)` and `set_script_timeout(5)`

  - [`set_page_load_timeout(time_to_wait)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout) : Sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an exception.
  - [`set_script_timeout(time_to_wait)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_script_timeout) : Sets the amount of time that the script should wait during an `execute_async_script` call before throwing an exception.

Hence the *Application Under Test* being dependent on *JavaScript* or *AJAX Calls* in presence of both the conditions raises *TimeoutException*.

- In your second scenario you have induced both `implicitly_wait(2)` and `WebDriverWait(driver, 2, 0.5)`.

  - [`implicitly_wait(time_to_wait)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.implicitly_wait) : Sets the timeout to implicitly wait for an element to be found or a command to complete.
  - [`WebDriverWait(driver, timeout, poll_frequency=0.5, ignored_exceptions=None)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) : Sets the timeout in-conjunction with different [`expected_conditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)
  - But you are experiancing *a very long timeout(40+ seconds)* as it is clearly mentioned in the [*docs*](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) **Do not mix implicit and explicit waits which can cause unpredictable wait times**

> **WARNING** : Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds, could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.

### Solution :

The best solution would be to remove all the instance of `implicitly_wait(time_to_wait)` and replace with `WebDriverWait()` for a stable behavior of the *Application Under Test (AUT)*.

---

### Update

As per your counter question, the current code block looks perfect. The measurement of time which you are seeing as `time used: 44.6049938202 s` is the time required for the *Web Page* to load completely and functionally that is the time required for the *Client* (i.e. the *Web Browser*) to return back the control to the *WebDriver* instance once **'document.readyState'** equals to **"complete"** is achieved. *Selenium* or as an user you have no control on this rendering process. However for a better performance you may follow the best practices as follows :

- Keep your **JDK** version updated currently [*Java SE Development Kit 8u162*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- Keep your **Selenium Client** version updated currently [*selenium 3.9.0*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)
- Keep your **WebDriver** version updated.
- Keep your **Web Browser** version updated.
- Clean you *Project Workspace* within your IDE regularly to build your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [***CCleaner***](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe away the OS chores before and after your *Test Suite* execution.
- If your *Web Browser* base version is too old uninstall the *Web Browser* through [***Revo Uninstaller***](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA released version of the *Web Browser*.
- Execute your *Test*.

Comment: Thank you for the hit. It solved the problem of exception,but there is still cases with long time loading. Now I only use `WebDriverWait()` to get the page source html(set timeout = 2s), and there still exist cases that used a long time to wait(about 20s+), so how can I stop the call when I don't want to wait for so long...?(the latest code is update in the description)

Comment: Check out my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: fine, I'll have another try and update my problem, thanks again

Comment: sure, I've used JDK 9.0 and Selenium 3.9.0 and it seems that everything works all right now : )