# How to combine implicit and explicit timeouts in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, implicitwait

I am using Selenium ChromeDriver with an implicit timeout:

```
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

In one of my tests I want to override this with an explicit timeout. Before reading a property I explicitely wait for the element to be found:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.example")));
```

I would expect this to take 120s to try to find the element, but it times out after just 5 seconds.

Comment: From [documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits): *"WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits"*

Comment: I agree totally with @Andersson answer, but I think if you absolutely have to, I would first change the implicit wait to also be 120 seconds, then change it back to 5 after what I would assume would be a successful match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation of [Explicit and Implicit Waits](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) it is clearly mentioned that:

> Do not mix ***implicit*** and ***explicit*** waits. Doing so can cause *unpredictable wait times*. For example setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds, could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.

Still if you have *implicit timeout* defined as:

```
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

Before inducing *explicit wait* for the element to be found you need to remove the *implicit timeout* as follows:

```
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.example")));
```

Once you are done with the *explicit wait*, you can re-configure back the *implicit timeout* again as:

```
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.example")));
//perform your action with the element
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```