# C# Selenium SendKeys() to element within iFrame

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to send keys to an element within an iFrame.
but it does not seem to be inputting any characters into the input.

```
IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.Name("email"));
email.SendKeys("someemail@input.com");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase the element is with an [**iFrame**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57554488/7429447) for the desired *FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52707885/7429447) for the desired [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62451578/7429447).
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *Name*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.TagName("iframe"));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("email"))).SendKeys("alexg1380@stackoverflow.com");
    ```
  - Using *CssSelector*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.CssSelector("iframe[frameAttribute='frameAttributeValue']"));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("[name='email'"))).SendKeys("alexg1380@stackoverflow.com");
    ```
  - Using *XPath*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//iframe[@frameAttribute='frameAttributeValue']"));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@name='email']"))).SendKeys("alexg1380@stackoverflow.com");
    ```

**PS**: In the above examples, *`frameAttribute`* and *`frameAttributeValue`* are placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

How about pasting to the element:

```cs
IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.Name("email"));
//email.SendKeys("someemail@input.com");
Clipboard.SetText("someemail@input.com");
email.textbox.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.LeftShift + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Insert);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should go to the iframe firstly before you send_keys to input

view the document
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/

```
driver.switch_to.frame("passport_iframe")
```

or

```
# switching to second iframe based on index
iframe = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')[1]

# switch to selected iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

after you finish send_keys and want to leave the iframe, you should using this line

```
# switch back to default content
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```