# ScrollDown in table on a website usinig Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i try to scroll down in a table on a website with the following code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

if __name__ == '__main__':  
  WAIT = 1
  print(f"Checking Browser driver...")
  os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = '0' 
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
  srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         
  
  link = "https://www.appliancepartspros.com/ge-dryer-timer-knob-we1m654-ap3995088.html"
  driver.get (link)     
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//h2[text()="Cross Reference and Model Information"]'))))         
  tmpBODY = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="m-bsc"]/a[@name="crossref"]')
  for _ in range(5):
    tmpBODY.send_keys (Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

But i allways get this error-message:

```
(selenium) C:\DEV\Fiverr\TRY\biglaundrystore>python try.py
Checking Browser driver...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Fiverr\TRY\biglaundrystore\try.py", line 31, in <module>
    tmpBODY.send_keys (Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 231, in send_keys       
    self._execute(
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 404, in _execute        
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.127)
```

This is the table i would like to scrolldown - as you can see the page-downs are not working as expected:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried another element? For example, last table row.

Comment: Which element should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found a solution using this code:

(probably not the most elegant solution - but it seems its doing what i need at the end)

```
import os
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

if __name__ == '__main__':  
  WAIT = 1
  print(f"Checking Browser driver...")
  os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = '0' 
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
  srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         
  
  link = "https://www.appliancepartspros.com/ge-dryer-timer-knob-we1m654-ap3995088.html"
  driver.get (link)  
  lastCounts = 0   
  while True:   
    print(f"Reading elements found {lastCounts}")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="xmodellist"]//tr[last()]'))))      
    time.sleep(WAIT)
    soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source, 'lxml')  
    worker = soup.find("div", {"id": "xmodellist"})  
    worker = worker.find_all("tr")
    if len(worker) == lastCounts:
      break
    lastCounts = len(worker)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a iframe and you can search "iframe" in page source, you should go to iframe firstly, then scroll down

and you can use scroll to go down

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions.wheel_input import ScrollOrigin
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
scroll_origin = ScrollOrigin.from_viewport(0, 0)
ActionChains(driver).scroll_from_origin(scroll_origin, 0, kkk_y).perform()
```

this answer maybe helpful

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76598852/17601704

view the document

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/wheel/#scroll-to-element
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/

Comment: Hello - i can see serverl iframes on the site. But no one is related to the table.