# Selenium and DevTools cant locate correct Xpath and its not inside an iframe

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to login in a page ([url](https://www.santander.com.br/empresas)) and selenium its not even been able to send input keys.
I tried:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@formcontrolname="ag"]')
```

I also tried to pick up by ID but its generated dynamically.

Even though the element its there in the page selenium cant find it.
I also tried manually using DevTools and no success, something seems to be blocking me from using scripts and I cant find it.

Element Im trying to send input:

```
<input mask="0000" type="text" formcontrolname="ag" style="background-color: #f0f0f0; border: 0px; width: 4rem; font-size: 14px;" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid dss-form-field__input" id="nhqkx-181131441b-11333-14a03-19d73-1142d11a351af5a">
```

Edit:
There isnt a iframe in devtools console, but I saw this strange tag which I dont know if its blocking me from walking with xpath

```
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-THV465P"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
 element = wait.until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='nhqkx-181131441b-11333-14a03-19d73-1142d11a351af5a']"))
 )
 element.send_keys("please replace your content")
```

Comment: The ID "nhqkx-181131441b-11333-14a03-19d73-1142d11a351af5a" changes every time you access the website and even if you try use this in devtools manually it wont work for an unkown reason

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/76598852/17601704

you should go to the iframe firstly before you send_keys to input

view the document
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/

```
driver.switch_to.frame("passport_iframe")
```

or

```
# switching to second iframe based on index
iframe = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')[1]

# switch to selected iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

after you finish send_keys and want to leave the iframe, you should using this line

```
# switch back to default content
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: the problem its there's no iframe in it as I mentioned