# Selenium implicit vs explicit wait

Tags: selenium-webdriver

what is the difference between implicit and explicit wait at driver level. Which one is driver level wait. If we give implicit and explicit wait in our code. Which one will have first priority.

Comment: Possible dublicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404160/when-to-use-explicit-wait-vs-implicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656615/what-is-difference-between-implicit-wait-vs-explicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between Implicit wait Vs. Explicit wait in selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656615/what-is-difference-between-implicit-wait-vs-explicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

implicit wait is implemented in the driver. explicit wait is implement in the selenium library in the programming language your code is written in.

it is not defined which will have priority if implicit and explicit is mixed.

read here for more info:

- [Combining implicit wait and explicit wait together results in unexpected wait times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164742/combining-implicit-wait-and-explicit-wait-together-results-in-unexpected-wait-ti/15174978#15174978) answer from jim evans, maintainer of selenium
- http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2017/07/02/part-6-waits-in-selenium-what-happens-when-we-mix-implicit-wait-and-explicit-wait/

tl;dr: if you mix you will have a bad time.