# How exactly explicit wait is different from implicit except(Conditional wait) as both wait execute next step before specified time completes?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

As per my knowledge, the explicit wait is a conditional wait and it would continue to execute the next step if the element gets found before the time specified. As shown in the code, the implicit wait should not execute next step even if the element gets found before 10secs, but it immediately execute next step i.e.within 2secs. It would not continue to poll DOM for entire 10secs. Also please suggest how to decide which wait to use as per examples? I have gone through many questions but all are copy paste, expecting answers at the architecture level.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
String appUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/";
driver.get(appUrl);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between Implicit wait Vs. Explicit wait in selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656615/what-is-difference-between-implicit-wait-vs-explicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

### ImplicitWait

[ImplicitWait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) is to specify the amount of time the *WebDriver* instance i.e. the *driver* should wait when searching for an element if it is not immediately present in the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) in-terms of `NANOSECONDS`, `MICROSECONDS`, `MILLISECONDS`, `SECONDS`, `MINUTES`, `HOURS` or `DAYS` when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is **0** which means the `driver` when finds an instruction to find an element or elements, the search starts and results are available on immediate basis.

In this case, after a fresh loading of a Webpage an element or elements may be / may not be found on an immediate search. So your `Automation Script` may be facing any of these exceptions:

- [`NoSuchElementException`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html)
- [`TimeoutException`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TimeoutException.html)
- [`ElementNotVisibleException`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotVisibleException.html)
- [`ElementNotSelectableException`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotSelectableException.html)

Hence we introduce **ImplicitWait**. By introducing *ImplicitWait* the *driver* will poll the [**DOM Tree**](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) until the element has been found for the configured amount of time looking out for the element or elements before throwing a [NoSuchElementException](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html). By that time the element or elements for which you had been looking for may be available in the *HTML DOM*. As in your code you have already set *ImplicitWait* to a value of **10** seconds, the *driver* will poll the *HTML DOM* for **10** seconds.

- *Java*:

  ```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```

Finally, once you set the **`ImplicitWait`**, the **`WebDriver`** instance i.e. the **`driver`** is able to carry this configuration  till its lifetime. But if you need to change the coarse of time for the **`WebDriver`** instance i.e. the **`driver`** to **`wait`** then you can reconfigure it as follows:

- *Java*:

  ```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```

If at any point of time you want to nullify the **`ImplicitWait`** you can reconfigure it as follows:

- *Java*:

  ```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```

You can find a detailed discussion in [Using implicit wait in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium)

---

### ExplicitWait

[ExplicitWait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) is a code block you define, configure and implement for the **WebDriver** instance to wait for a certain condition to be met before proceeding for the next line of code.  There are some methods that helps us to implement **ExplicitWait** that will wait only as long as required. **WebDriverWait** in combination with **ExpectedCondition** is one of the way **ExplicitWait** can be achieved.

### An Example:

- *Java*:

  ```
  driver.get("http://www.example.com/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("element_css"))).click();
  ```

### Explanation:

This implementation of **ExplicitWait** waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a `TimeoutException` or if it finds the element then it will return within 0 to 10 seconds. **WebDriverWait** by default calls the `ExpectedCondition` every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully. A successful return value for the `ExpectedCondition` function type is a `Boolean` value of true or a not-null object.

### Expected Conditions:

There are some frequently encountered conditions when automating Web Browsers for `Testing Web/Mobile Applications`. The Java, C# and Python bindings include those convenient methods so we don’t have to write-up an **`ExpectedCondition`** class ourselves or create our own utility package for them. Some of the **`Expected Conditions`** are:

- `alertIsPresent()`
- `elementToBeClickable(locator)`
- `elementToBeSelected(WebElement)`
- `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(locator)`
- `invisibilityOf(element)`

Here you can find about the all the methods supported by [Expected Conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html).

You can find a detailed discussion in [Replace implicit wait with explicit wait (selenium webdriver & java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759).

---

> **`Note`** : **Do not mix** **`implicit and explicit waits`**. Doing so can cause **`unpredictable wait times`**. For example setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds, could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.