# I am trying to open a response of a form in java but since it takes some time for it to load, java is not able to get the right content

Tags: java, url, web-scraping, html

How do I wait till the response is loaded and then get the page?

```
        url = new URL("http://somesite.com/sompage.jsp?somefield=something");           

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                           new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }


        br.close();
```

Comment: The webpage has to get some values from a webservice.
So what I see in html is "Async response not received yet."

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a third-party library called [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/). This is basically a headless browser that can wait until the element you are looking for loads completely. A simple example taken from other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736027/webdriver-wait-for-element-using-java) would be:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutValue);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url = new URL("http://somesite.com/sompage.jsp?somefield=something");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000); // 1000 milliseconds is one second. Wait for IM Ticket Generation
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}
br.close();
```

Adding sleep before using the resource worked.