# Page Title is not captured correctly in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

consider i am having two pages, first page -Login page and second Page -welcome page. If i provide the user credential in the login page, then it will be redirected into the welcome page.

I need to verify the page title in both the pages. so, i have used driver.getTitle(); after the page navigation steps. But, it is displaying the first page title and second page tile is not displaying

Thanks
Subbu

Comment: Is the welcome page in a second window?

Comment: welcome page is opening in the same window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most like a timing issue - *you are getting the title while the second page is not loaded yet*. Use Explicit Wait via [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) class to wait for the second/welcome page to load ([sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736027/webdriver-wait-for-element-using-java)).

You may even use "title" specific wait conditions, see:

- [`titleIs`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#titleIs(java.lang.String))
- [`titleContains`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#titleContains(java.lang.String))

Comment: I have used the title contains condition as below                                                       loginButton.submit();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
System.out.println(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Welcome")));                                                                                                                             But still page name is not found correctly seems and error is throwing as "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 100 seconds waiting for title to contain "Welcome". Current title: "Login"

Comment: I am getting the TimeoutException and mentioned my sample code. Please help me

Comment: @Subburaj oh, sorry, decided you've solved that. Okay, do you see what is happening in the browser at the moment the form is submitted?

Comment: @Subburaj okay, we have a different issue then - I think you should elaborate this into a new question if you need the community's help. Make sure to provide as much detail as you can. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alecexe, I have used the above code with Firefox Driver , then it is working fine without an any issue.But when i used with IE Driver, then only page title is not getting captured correctly and getting TimeoutException.      Do  you have any idea on this?

Comment: After adding the explicit wait with titlecontains method. Page title is getting captured correctly in chrome/firefox.

Answer (score 2):

you must add explicit wait and check whether second page is loading in the given time or not.