# How to print the elements having common css value in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.ignitionone.com/company/careers/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.teal")).click();      

Thread.sleep(2000);
String s2 =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#board_title")).getText();

List<WebElement>d_details = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".level-0"));
    for(int i=0; i<d_details.size();i++){
    WebElement element = d_details.listIterator();
    String innerhtml = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");

    System.out.println("Available openings  are" + innerhtml);
}


System.out.println("The title is " + s2);

driver.quit();
```

This is my code.I am trying to print the available job openings in different areas in the webpage. Can someone please help to understand whats going wring in here.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is wrong with the code? Thanks.

Comment: yes the for loop is not working for me. so nothing is printing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *type casting problem* on this line:

```
WebElement element = d_details.listIterator();
```

A better way to iterate over the elements would be this:

```
List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".level-0"));
for (WebElement result: results) {
    String innerhtml = result.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    System.out.println("Available openings  are" + innerhtml);
}
```

Note that you may also be experiencing a *timing issue.* You should replace your `Thread.sleep()` calls with Explicit Wait commands, check out this topic:

- [WebDriver - wait for element using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11736027/771848)

Comment: Thankyou. Did the code work for you? I am still getting error in the loop with you code also

Comment: @Joe12 Yup, I have a working code. What error you are getting? Thanks.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Permission denied to access property "_wrapped"
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, appBuildId=20161019084923, version=49.0.2, platform=XP, proxy=Proxy(), command_id=1.0, specificationLevel=0.0, acceptSslCerts=false, processId=10516.0, browserVersion=49.0.2, platformVersion=10.0, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=win

Comment: @Joe12 ah, I had it too, solved by updating firefox and geckodriver to the latest versions.

Comment: whats your current version of both

Comment: @Joe12 firefox 54, geckodriver 0.17.

Comment: That worked . this is the result i am gettting.But how do i get  only 'customer service europe', 'project manger', 'location from this
  <h2 id="17759">Customer Success Europe</h2>

  <div class="opening" department_id="17759" office_id="10738" data-office-10738="true" data-department-17759="true">
  <a data-mapped="true" href="/ignitionone/jobs/670900">Project Manager</a>
  <br>
  <span class="location">Brussels</span>
</div>

Comment: @Joe12 If the answer has solved your problem, kindly mark it as the accepted answer. If you encounter a new problem or if you have a new question, please consider opening a new topic instead.