# Selenium - after page change cannot find element even it is visible

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium and java, after clicking on one button I land on another page and I see the input tag that I am looking in the viewport

after waiting for page to load with

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

in order to get the tag I use the [scrollIntoView()](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/scroll-element-view-selenium-javascript/) and search for the element by id using javascript inside java this way:

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementId').scrollIntoView(true);");
```

but the problem is that document.getElementById('elementId') returns null; I tried it also in the firefox webdriver console with the same result.

If I execute  `document.getElementById('elementId')` on the same page using firefox console but without using Selenium webdriver I get the tag as expected.

Why am I getting this null using Selenium? How to fix it?

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736027/webdriver-wait-for-element-using-java

Comment: Did you check it is not inside any frame/iframe?

Comment: yes, it is contained in an iframe tag

Comment: then use this before `driver.switchTo().frame("frame/iframe name/id")`..Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the below code before the scrollIntoView()  code

```
  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
```

IF any element resides under iframe tag you should switch your driver to iframe using above

If you need to switch your driver in default mode then u need to use below code

```
 driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
```

If the element is under modal then use it

```
driver.switchTo().frame("ModelFrameTitle");
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement()
```

Comment: what if the object is a modal instead of an iframe?

Comment: my modal does not have any title and it seems to throw exception if I search the element by class

Comment: Try post a new question with providing html dom.