# Locating webelement using nested xpath in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I like to test a complex webapplication written in GWT, and I have some question about how Selenium works.

I have two calendars (monthCalendar1 and monthcalender2).
Both have a label with the month and year

[image of calendars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Kr2.jpg)

I can reach the month and year label in the second calendar with next statement :

```
WebElement webelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'monthCalendar2')]//div[contains(@class,'monthAndYearLabel')]"));
    String s = webelement.getText();
    //s = December 2018
```

But I would like to split the website in logical parts, so I want to use :

```
  WebElement webelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'monthCalendar2')]"));
        WebElement webelement2 = webelement.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'monthAndYearLabel')]"));
    webelement2.getText();
    String s = webelement2.getText();
    //s = November 2018
```

It looks like webelement2 starts searching from the start of the website, and not from webelement. Can I use the second approach? How?

Kind regards
Wim

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.` before the first `//` to tell the `xpath` to use current context

```
webelement.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'monthAndYearLabel')]"));
```

Comment: Mmm, that doesn't work. I get : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[contains(@class,'monthAndYearLabel')]"}

Comment: @WimWillemsens I can't help much without the html, but this is the way. Maybe try adding some wait https://stackoverflow.com/a/11738528/5168011

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry it looks that this is working well. Some copy paste issue. Thanhx!