# No such element found selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have been trying to automate a browser operation via selenium, google.com will be opened, but the text is not searched. The code used is:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Microsoft" + Keys.Enter);
```

Exception message is:

> Unable to locate element:{"method":"id";"selector";"lst-ib"}

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the element with `id="lst-ib"` at the link you provided, but if you're interested in sending the keys to the search bar, you may instead be able to find it by name like:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='q']")).SendKeys("Microsoft" + Keys.Enter);
```

Alternatively, I might have missed the element with the id you specified above, in which case you can try to wait for it to appear on the page using [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736027/webdriver-wait-for-element-using-java).