# Unable to select option from dropdown in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium and I am finding difficulty in getting option from dropdown also how to take className if the class has space in between,please help me,thanks in advance.

I used select with selectbyindex also partialvisibletext but nothing worked.

This is the HTML code

```
<div class="form-group" xpath="1">
  <label>Source of Info</label>      
 <!-- <select class="form-control flat-control-inner" ng-model="userPersonal.sourceOfInfo.id" required> 
  <option ng-value="0">--Select--</option>          
  <option data-ng-repeat="si in sourceOfInfoList" data-ng-value="{{si.id}}" ng-selected="si.id==userPersonal.sourceOfInfo.id">{{si.name}}</option>                                  
  </select> -->
     <select class="form-control flat-control-inner dateonly ng-valid ng-touched ng-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-model="userPersonal.sourceOfInfo.id" ng-options="si.id as si.name for si in sourceOfInfoList" style="">
      <option value="" class="">--Select--</option>
      <option label="Newspaper" value="number:1">Newspaper</option>
      <option label="Facebook" value="number:2" selected="selected">Facebook</option>
      <option label="Twitter" value="number:3">Twitter</option>
      <option label="Television" value="number:4">Television</option>
      <option label="Others" value="number:5">Others</option>
    </select>   
  </div>
```

This is what I tried

```
WebElement source_dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='form-control flat-control-inner dateonly ng-valid ng-touched ng-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse']"));
Select source = new Select(source_dropdown);
source.selectByIndex(1);
```

This what I am getting in console

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@class='form-control flat-control-inner dateonly ng-valid ng-touched ng-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse']"}
```

Comment: Add some [wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736027/webdriver-wait-for-element-using-java)

Comment: tried with that too using implicitwait

Comment: First confirm whether you can find this by your locator manually, if yes then use explicit wait like element to be clickable and then try else try with other locator.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebDriverWait` to handle dynamic element.If the code not work Please check if there any `iframe` available and if then you have to switch to `iframe` first to access the `select` element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement source_dropdown=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@class='form-control flat-control-inner dateonly ng-valid ng-touched ng-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse']")));
Select source = new Select(source_dropdown);
source.selectByIndex(1);
```

Comment: No iframe is there

Comment: You mean the above code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your are unable to find the drop-down itself, try xpath with different attribute like

```
//select[@ng-model='userPersonal.sourceOfInfo.id']
```

or

```
//div[@class='form-group']/following::select
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to select option with displayed text matching the argument

```
//xpath = select[@ng-model='userPersonal.sourceOfInfo.id']
WebElement dropDownListBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@ng-model='userPersonal.sourceOfInfo.id']"));
Select clickThis = new Select(dropDownListBox);
clickThis.selectByVisibleText(value);//value is an option visible in dropdown
```