# How can I wait for Mobile element

Tags: android, appium, driver

I would like to wait for MobilElement, not sure what is the correct way.

Using Appium, Selenium and Java to create some automation tests, but running all using emulator and sometimes I need to wait little bit for element, I would like to use something what I use in webElement. Reason why I use find by class is in application there are no ids and I can not change it.

```
public static MobileElement myButton(AndroidDriver driver, int index) {
    List<MobileElement> button = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.Button"));

    return  button.get(index);
}
```

Emulator is slow for me so I would like to use something like  waitForElement method

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11738528/7450414

Comment: thank you but in my case I wan to wait for MobileElement not WebElement :(

Comment: Why can't you change your code to use WebElement?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an **Implicit wait**. Which is basically waiting for a certain amount of time before throwing an exception that it cannot find the element on the page.

```
WebDriver driver => new FirefoxDriver();

 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 driver.get("http://url_that_delays_loading");

 WebElement myDynamicElement = driver.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
```

Another way is to use **Expected Conditions wait** to evaluate that something is neither null nor false.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

 WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(>someid>)));
```

To wait for the page to load to set the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error. If the timeout is negative, page loads can be indefinite.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(100, SECONDS);
```

**Thread.Sleep** also can be used, but it's not an ideal wait declaration.

```
 thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but in my case I don't want to define Webdriver, I want to use Android driver. I don't test app in any browser, I am testing mobile application and all tests are done there. Using atm thread.sleep but I want to change for wait for element etc

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Try use `visibilityOf`, like this:

```
public static MobileElement myButton(AndroidDriver driver, int index) {
    List<MobileElement> button = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.Button"));

    //update here
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(button.get(index)));
    return  button.get(index);
}
```

`30` in second.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if I use this code I can see . The method visibilityOfAllElements(WebElement...) in the type ExpectedConditions is not applicable for the arguments (List<MobileElement>). So I was trying with something like this. new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy((By) enrollKeyboard)); but then I can this java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.By :(

Comment: Thank you very much, code is correct now, but I don't think is is actually waits :(
I set wait for 2 minutes "new WebDriverWait(driver, 120)" but is fails without waits 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, just change this line:

```
List<MobileElement> button = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.Button"));
```

to this assuming [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) class usage for [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) implementation :

```
List<MobileElement> button = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("android.widget.Button")))
        .stream()
        .map(element -> (MobileElement) element)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Going forward you can consider implementing [Page Object Model](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) design pattern and use [@AndroidFindBy](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/pagefactory/AndroidFindBy.html) annotation, check out https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/Page-objects.md for example code.