# Selenium Webdriver: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located in headless mode for IAP Google

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to use headless mode on application having a step with IAP google. It runs without errors when headless mode is off. When the headless mode is On selenium can not locate the element.

I don't know how to fix that. I've tried a lot of configurations for chromedriver but still have the same error.

```
public class Hooks {

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        String chromeDriverPath = "C:\\Selenium\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
        options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080");
        //options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
```

Error when try to locate the element:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //button[text() = 'Esqueceu seu e-mail?'] (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
```

Steps to locate the element:

```
public BaseClass(WebDriver driver) {
        BaseClass.driver = driver;
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    }
    public void waitVisibility(By elementBy) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(elementBy));
    }
    public void isDisplayed(By elementBy) {
        waitVisibility(elementBy);
        driver.findElement(elementBy).isDisplayed();
    }
   public void checkElement() {
        isDisplayed(headerLoginGooglePage);
    }
```

The complete error stack trace

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a) on port 39113
Only local connections are allowed.
dez 12, 2019 4:25:32 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFORMAÇÕES: Detected dialect: OSS
    Dado que o usuário acesse a url do sistema SMAPP Parts and Maintenance          # LoginSteps.queOUsuarioAcesseUrlSistemaSMAPP()
    Entao exibe tela padrão de login por conta Google                               # LoginSteps.exibeTelaPadraoLoginContaGoogle()
      org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //button[text() = 'Esqueceu seu e-mail?'] (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at pageobjects.BaseClass.waitVisibility(BaseClass.java:21)
    at pageobjects.BaseClass.isDisplayed(BaseClass.java:51)
    at pageobjects.MaintenanceTimeLinePages.visualizarElementoTelaGoogle(MaintenanceTimeLinePages.java:109)
    at step_definitions.LoginSteps.exibeTelaPadraoLoginContaGoogle(LoginSteps.java:34)
    at ✽.exibe tela padrão de login por conta Google(src/test/resources/features/Login.feature:7)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[text() = 'Esqueceu seu e-mail?']"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-AJU29UT', ip: '192.168.12.226', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde371..., userDataDir: C:\Users\ZUPPER\AppData\Loc...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51880}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 78.0.3904.108, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: b148fc1021de85032649ce461e775ab2
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//button[text() = 'Esqueceu seu e-mail?']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
    at pageobjects.BaseClass.waitVisibility(BaseClass.java:21)
    at pageobjects.BaseClass.isDisplayed(BaseClass.java:51)
    at pageobjects.MaintenanceTimeLinePages.visualizarElementoTelaGoogle(MaintenanceTimeLinePages.java:109)
    at step_definitions.LoginSteps.exibeTelaPadraoLoginContaGoogle(LoginSteps.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:32)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:26)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:40)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:102)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:83)
    at cucumber.api.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:58)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:80)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:117)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:55)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$1.evaluate(Cucumber.java:126)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: adding some implicit wait might help ```driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);```  But this could lead to some other issues.

Comment: Instead of an implicit wait, try a `WebDriverWait`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736027/webdriver-wait-for-element-using-java

Comment: @AndreSousa Update the question with the relevant HTML, your code trials and the complete error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB I updated the question. Do you need more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a) on port 39113
Only local connections are allowed.
dez 12, 2019 4:25:32 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFORMAÇÕES: Detected dialect: OSS
    Dado que o usuário acesse a url do sistema SMAPP Parts and Maintenance          # LoginSteps.queOUsuarioAcesseUrlSistemaSMAPP()
    Entao exibe tela padrão de login por conta Google                               # LoginSteps.exibeTelaPadraoLoginContaGoogle()
      org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //button[text() = 'Esqueceu seu e-mail?'] (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
.
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[text() = 'Esqueceu seu e-mail?']"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-AJU29UT', ip: '192.168.12.226', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to communicate with **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.43*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.43*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v69-71**

- You are using *chrome=78.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v78.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 78**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.141.59*.

So there is a clear mismatch between *Selenium Client v3.141.59* , *ChromeDriver v2.43* and the *Chrome Browser v78.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: How can I check what is my Web Client?

Comment: @AndreSousa The Chrome/Firefox/IE browsers are your client, some calls em as web client :)

Comment: I made all the points of the solution that you said, except execute as non-root user. Still not working, but I will try this for make sure that is the problem.
I change the browser to Firefox and works.

Comment: I just finish all the points and still nothing. Looks like make no sense works on Firefox and not works in Chrome. ;/