# Problem with authentication popup using Selenium Webdirver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to handle authentication popup using Selenium Webdirve in Java. Here are the things I have tried :

[![Pop-up I am dealing with][1]][1]

````
//Selenium-WebDriver Java Code for entering Username & Password as below:
 driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("username" + Keys.TAB + "password");
 driver.switchTo().alert().accept();```
Using AutoIT :

Send("username{TAB}myPassword{ENTER}")```



Selenium-WebDriver Java Code for entering Username & Password as below:

driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("myPassword");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();



I have used the above-mentioned methods but it doesn't work. Also , I am not getting any errors in console .


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSkbs.png
````

Comment: So the popup you are seeing is Basic authentication popup ? Can you share a snapshot to confirm it ? Also have you checked that you are waiting for enough time before sending AutoIt command to fill up the information ?

Comment: I think the pop-up you talking about it is an authentication popup. Authentication popup and Alert are 2 different things. And screenshot will be helpful.

Comment: I am not able to add a screenshot over here .I tried but its not working :(

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the element first.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("password")));
```

[Checkout this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736027/webdriver-wait-for-element-using-java)